# Disable "vibrate" in lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, vibration

When in lock-screen, I have to move the middle circle over the "lock" on right hand side. The device vibrates 3x during it - is it possible to disable all the vibrations?

(Using ICS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not an option.

Actually this seems like a bug as this should be controlled by the option, `Vibrate on Touch` under `Sound` in the settings.  Either that, or the option `Vibrate  on Touch` should remain visible when setting the screen security option to `Slide` in the `Security` part of the settings.

You may want to report this as a bug to the Android team using the [Android Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

Settings - sound & notification - Other sounds

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Although above steps may help answer the question, you should include relevant details in your own words, explaining how it is done, and add screen shots to exactly locate the settings to make your answer more constructive!